# Adding commas to numbers when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add commas when the user type a number. What is the correct syntax to select the `input form-control` class with attribute `number` type in Jquery?

EDIT: I can't change the HTML code since it is outputted from Django with Bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
<input class="form-control" id="id_step2-number_2"
       name="step2-number_2" type="number">
<span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='number']").keyup(function(event){
        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "")
            .split("").reverse().join("");
          
        var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(
            num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("")
                .reverse().join("")
        );
          
        console.log(num2);

        // the following line has been simplified.
        // Revision history contains original.
        $this.val(num2);
    });
});
    
function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){
    if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){
        return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            
    }
    return convertString;
}
```

**JSFiddle Link**
https://jsfiddle.net/yWTLk/767/

Comment: Why don't you use autonumeric plugin?

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't know the correct syntax to get JQuery to point at the text input I posted.

Comment: `$this.val()` is hugely more efficient as `this.value`.

Comment: You may be able to use this fiddle as a base: http://jsfiddle.net/GH05T/rd4xsvxd/

Answer (score 19):

First of all, you can't use `input type=number`, because it won't allow the character `,` which you are using to notate number group.

Second, with a good regular expression, this is actually super easy, and really no need for reverse and reverse, which is boring.

```
var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "");
var num2 = num.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
```

The first line removes commas from input value.
The second line is magic, it splits the value into groups of 3 from last to first, then join with comma. For example, `'1234567'` will become `['1', '234', '567']`.

I use `split` here is just to show the power of RegExp, in practice we don't need to split and join, just replace directly:

```
var num2 = num.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$&,');
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/myst/yWTLk/773/)

But, the real magic is, I bet you would yell, `toLocaleString`! What?!

```
(1234567).toLocaleString() // "1,234,567"
```

Comment: What would you do about the decimal point though?  If you use a decimal point for cents it breaks it.

Comment: @James go ahead with `toLocaleString()`

Comment: I did try that first but it didn't work.  No errors either. I was in the latest version of FF.  I'll look into it more on Monday though.  Thanks.

Comment: @James Oops, I guess you have a different locale setting from mine? As JS has a incomplete RE implementation, and I'm not so specialized in RE, I doubt it's possible to achive with only one RE. But personally, if things go complicated I'd rather choose some "stupid" approach, at least much more maintainable :)

Comment: But the problem is that cursor goes to the end always. Lets say I want to delete to numbers, I press 2 times backspace and after first press it goes to end - very bad.

Answer (score 8):

Using the input type "number" seems to prevent inserting commas into the input field with Javascript. If you'd like to insert commas, you may want to use a "text" input instead, but this will prevent numeric validation on browsers with Javascript disabled.

The fun will never end, it's HTML5.

Comment: this should be addd as a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Change `type="number"` to `type="text"` because you can't put comma into number.

```
<input class="form-control" id="id_step2-number_2"
       name="step2-number_2" type="text">
```

Check updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yWTLk/769/)

Answer (score 0):

As many people are not using jQuery nowadays, here is a simple example with vanilla javascript.
You might have different use cases to add comma-separated values for numbers. Here is a complete guide to [using commas as thousand separated using javascript](https://latestjavascript.com/2-ways-to-add-comma-as-thousand-separator-in-javascript/).

```js
let inputElement = document.querySelector("#number_element");
         inputElement.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
      var tempNumber = inputElement.value.replace(/,/gi, "");
      var commaSeparatedNumber = tempNumber.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
      inputElement.value = commaSeparatedNumber;
     })
```

```html
<input id="number_element" type="text">
<span>.00</span>
```